# Unable to enter if statement after raw_input

Tags: python, if-statement, input

Whenever I call a function within a while loop in my project it will do absolute nothing according to the function just being called and will just continue to refresh the loop like nothing happened.

Here is a simple example I wrote demonstrating the problem. By running the code you will be shown a menu and you will need to enter a choice from the menu. When doing so a few "if" statements will check which option you chose and call and execute the code below them if the choice doesn't belong to any of the statements the menu will just refresh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time

def test():
    x = True
    while True:
        if not x:
            print "You need to type 1\n"
        choice = raw_input("type 1 here: ")
        if choice == 1:
            print 'Works!\n'
            time.sleep(5)
            break
        else:
            x = False

def test2():
    print "Test123\n"

try:
    while True:
        os.system("clear")

        menu_choice = raw_input("Enter Choice: ")

        if menu_choice == 1:
            test()

        if menu_choice == 2:
            test2()

        if menu_choice == 3:
            os.system("python")

except:
    pass
```

Comment: You are mixing string type and int type. raw_input returns a string. If you want to use it in a int context, try int(choice) / int(menu_choice)

Comment: Thank you :) just changed the == 1 to == "1" and etc and it works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `raw_input` returns a string and you'll need to cast it. BUT, you'd likely need to catch a ValueError for anything typed not a number.

Instead, you could do this

```
 if choice == '1'
```

Same for `menu_choice`